# Firebase analytics dashboard filter by country not available

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I wanted to apply filter in my firebase analytics dashboard with country.
In my filter user property (country) is not at all listing.
Among the default collected user properties only below listed properties are listed in the filter:

> - age
> - app version
> - device model
> - gender
> - new/established
> - os version

In create audience section, all user properties are listed, and property data is getting collected in firebase.

How can I enable filter by country in my dashboard.

Comment: File a bug report or Feature Request on Firebase Support channel.

Answer (score 15):

To filter by country in firebase, you need to create an audience first:

1. Open your firebase console and select your project
2. In the left sidebar menu Go to Analytics > Audiences > New Audience
3. In the popup window , set a title of your audience and in the dropdown 
   menu below, select user property > country.
4. Finally chose the expression Ex: US / SP etc.. which depends on the users that you have.

Comment: But the audience does not include the past users ? Starts to 0 user. Right ?

Comment: @Regis_AG Right, you need to wait for the audience to fill with users... Quite inconvenient.

Comment: Still starts at 0 users. What a shitty tool.

Answer (score 4):

New audience -> Templates -> Demographics -> Filter by [country id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

[image: firebase filter by country]